# R crashing when attempting to create a large matrix

Tags: r, matrix, r-bigmemory

I am attempting to create a large matrix of 0s in order to then convert it into a network object after inserting and transforming some data. The data I'm using is a list of user IDs and their friends' IDs. I'm using the code that I found here [http://www.shizukalab.com/toolkits/sna/sna_data] to transform the connections between users and friends into 1s. Then I can use `statnet` and `igraph` to analyze the data. The problem occurs when I attempt to create the matrix based on the dimensions of my data in that my R session keeps aborting.

In the interest of specificity, I'll show my whole process because I'm thinking that the problem is not a memory or system issue, but rather an issue with my data.

So I first subsetted the data to give me two columns, the user ID and their friends. Then I collapsed it and created a txt file from it, which I then scanned into memory.

```
registerDoMC(cores = 3)
library(bigmemory)

yelpNetwork <- select(training, c(4:5))
yelpNetwork$friends <- vapply(yelpNetwork$friends, paste, collapse = ",",  character(1L))
write.table(yelpNetwork, "yelpNetwork.txt", row.names = FALSE)

##Scan in a file with IDs as character strings {even if numeric"}, and with fields separated by commas
dat=scan("yelpNetwork.txt", what="character",sep="\n")
```

Here is a snippet of what `dat` looks like:

```
[1] "\"user_id\" \"friends\""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[2] "\"--0KsjlAThNWua2Pr4HStQ\" \"nELVJlkX8T0mUAArSPSJxw D4v0v5fHzxYLWaXl8gTHqQ 3Uj1YjuShWl6i5in-80sGw WmAhGvWfztnCNrGak8Zf-A VFL4LY37bEvyDPobGoxvXg tyRSwnzsdQDi4WlEBw5RCg VSP01oJh4hrM7KngLZStWw 7g3CFT7P4yfRmPm1rDimSA np418-wlhgpteqef4rn_nQ vK8Ymi2Z6rk3OgkTuMt6Fw\""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[3] "\"--20-ljZD5NnAnkwBBC_uQ\" \"tRN04Yo_qnir-y9RXqQ5qg\""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[4] "\"--2QZsyXGz1OhiD4-0FQLQ\" \"\""
```

Then I read in the length of `dat` to establish the dimensions and try to create the matrix. Rstudio runs for what seems like a long time and then crashes.

```
# Store the number of lines in the file
dym=length(dat)

# Create a dymXdym matrix of zeros
m<-matrix(data=0,nrow=dym,ncol=dym)
```

Again, I don't think it's a memory or system issue. Based on other StackOverflow discussions, I'm using the `bigmemory` package and am running on three of my four cores. Here is part of the `sessionInfo` and I have 16GB RAM. I'm also running Rstudio v. 0.99.486, which I just upgraded a couple of weeks ago.

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan)
```

I'm not the most advanced R user, so I may be overlooking something obvious. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: how big is the matrix you are trying to initialize? i.e. what is the value of `dym`

Comment: Unsure if this is still an open problem, but I don't see you using `bigmemory` anywhere. Instead of creating a regular matrix, you want to create a big.matrix object. Take a look at the examples in ?big.matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to an internal R-Limit of at most 2^31 cells in a matrix. R has a number of limits when you get to 2^31. As you want to pair every user with every other user, you will reach this limit with around 50000 users.

My suggestion would be to use sparse matrices. Presumably most of your users are only friends with a very small subset of the entire user list so your matrix is mostly zeros. Sparse matrices will also be much faster for these kind of problems.